# Gzip/Brotli compression with CloudFront doesn't work on URL rewriting?

Tags: url-rewriting, gzip, amazon-cloudfront, http-compression, brotli

CloudFront provides automatic compression of web pages.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html

The environment of our website is very typical, it is LAMP and the URL rewriting of each page is set up in .htaccess.
The URLs look like:

- `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159895/gzip-compression-with-cloudfront-doesnt-work`
- `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cloudfront+compression`

CloudFront's compression seems doesn't work on our rewritten URL pages (`Content-Type: text/html`, but they don't have any `filename.ext` in the URLs), whether it is **Gzip** or **Brotli**.

During repeated testing, I also invalidated the files from edge caches again and again.

To verify whether there is a URL rewriting problem, under the same environment and settings, the `.js` and `.css` files can be compressed and Brotli (`Content-Encoding: br`) is automatically used.

Does anyone have any successful experience with using CloudFront's compression on web pages that have had URLs rewritten?